# Post Meta for Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I am using WordPress to build a job website and a huge portion of my website is involved with storing and retrieving user information to and from the database.

There are three types of custom posts on the website Jobs, Resumes and Companies. Here are my questions :

1. Are the fields in the `wp_postmeta` table common to all of the post types. Meaning, if a Resume has `education_level` meta field, will Companies also have it?
2. How do I add more fields in the `wp_postmeta` table if that is required. I am looking for a method that involves writing code in the theme files and not directly adding fields to the database tables from PHPMyAdmin.

Any help on these topics is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1- Yes they are common to all post types but it can be changed for each and every post, and yes meta field will be the same for companies too.

2- Whenever you add a new post, there is an option of adding custom field box, by default it is disabled (You can enable it by checking the `Custom Field` box. from the screen options, at the top right of the post page).
There you can add a custom field box for your post.

If you want a custom field box with advance functionalities, then check [ACF Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

Comment: Hey, thank you for showing interest and answering my question. For some reason there is no option within the screen options for custom fields and I think that is probably because Jobs/Company/Resume are custom post type. If it isnt too much trouble can you have a look at add_meta_box() [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and let me know if this will do the trick?

Comment: I am trying to use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin for the same but it is not working. The plugin shows that it has created a custom field for me but it is not showing when I open the Resume post options (that is the post type for which I made the custom field). I also checked the database to see if the field has been added but I cannot find it there as well. Any idea why this is happening?